# pgfplots ycomb width

Tags: pgfplots

Is there a simple way to control the width\thickness of the strokes in the `ycomb/xcomb` commands proposed in `pgfplots`? Or should I dive into the source code to clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line width is a property of every single plot. So you can just add a corresponding option. Here is an example derived from the [pgfplots](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) manual.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot+[xcomb,line width=5pt] coordinates {%
        (4,0) (1,1) (2,2) (5,3) (6,4) (1,5)
      };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```